# expss mdset table with both counts and percentages

Tags: r, expss

For a multiple response (multiple dichotomy) set, I would like to make a simple table showing both counts and percents of valid responses.

```
checkall <- data.frame(ID=1:60, 
                     q1a=sample(c(0,1), size=60, replace=TRUE),
                     q1b=sample(c(0,1), size=60, replace=TRUE),
                     q1c=sample(c(0,1), size=60, replace=TRUE), 
                     q1d=sample(c(0,1), size=60, replace=TRUE),
                     q1e=sample(c(0,1), size=60, replace=TRUE),
                     q1f=sample(c(0,1), size=60, replace=TRUE),
                     q1g=sample(c(0,1), size=60, replace=TRUE),
                     q1h=sample(c(0,1), size=60, replace=TRUE))



calc_cro_cpct(checkall, mdset(q1a %to% q1h))

 |              | #Total |
 | ------------ | ------ |
 |          q1a |   53.3 |
 |          q1b |   48.3 |
 |          q1c |   43.3 |
 |          q1d |   43.3 |
 |          q1e |   41.7 |
 |          q1f |   55.0 |
 |          q1g |   63.3 |
 |          q1h |   48.3 |
 | #Total cases |   60.0 |

calc_cro_cases(checkall, mdset(q1a %to% q1h))

                         
 |              | #Total |
 | ------------ | ------ |
 |          q1a |     32 |
 |          q1b |     29 |
 |          q1c |     26 |
 |          q1d |     26 |
 |          q1e |     25 |
 |          q1f |     33 |
 |          q1g |     38 |
 |          q1h |     29 |
 | #Total cases |     60 |
```

Is there a way to get these into the same table, side by side?

I managed to make it work with `tidyverse` (without a total cases row).

```
library(tidyverse)
checkall %>% 
     select(q1a:q1h) %>% 
     summarize_all(sum, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
     pivot_longer(everything(), names_to="Choice", values_to = "count") %>% 
     mutate(percent=round(count/nrow(checkall), 3))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Choice count percent
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 q1a       32   0.533
2 q1b       29   0.483
3 q1c       26   0.433
4 q1d       26   0.433
5 q1e       25   0.417
6 q1f       33   0.55 
7 q1g       38   0.633
8 q1h       29   0.483
```

But I'd like to see if `expss` can do it because if the ease in computing valid percent (i.e. total cases reflects the number of observations that have at least one choice in the `mdset`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out while looking at the examples for *non* mdset tables:

```
  checkall %>% tab_cells(mdset(q1a %to% q1h)) %>%
    #tab_cols(q11) %>%
    tab_stat_cases(label = "freq") %>%
    tab_stat_cpct(label = "col %") %>%
    tab_pivot(stat_position = "inside_columns")

 |              | #Total |       |
 |              |   freq | col % |
 | ------------ | ------ | ----- |
 |          q1a |     32 |  53.3 |
 |          q1b |     29 |  48.3 |
 |          q1c |     26 |  43.3 |
 |          q1d |     26 |  43.3 |
 |          q1e |     25 |  41.7 |
 |          q1f |     33 |  55.0 |
 |          q1g |     38 |  63.3 |
 |          q1h |     29 |  48.3 |
 | #Total cases |     60 |  60.0 |
```